# Reading MXD files created by MidexPro

Tags: export

Has anyone ever written their own code to look inside the MXD files created by medical practice management software MidexPro? I would like to export appointments from Aptxt1.mxd (the diary file).

I know the diary screen has an Export button, but it would be preferable to run a program on a schedule with no human interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Aptxt1.mxd only stores a list of appointment types, not the actual appointments.  To get anything useful you'd also have to convert numerous other files to be able to reconstruct the whole diary.  I have developed utilities to convert all MidexPro data into our own system, Practice Manager, as we regularly convert users across to our software.  We also have web based diary booking systems, if that's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Like you, I just need to extract data to copy it to our own system. I just need the name/date/time for each appointment. If you are able to share any more information that would be rally helpful, but I know you won't want to give away all your hard work! What is the overall strategy for the MXD structure - is it a series of fixed-length fields in a certain order, with certain delimiters? Or are there headers which specify the length of each following part? I see some of the files are almost plain text...but not quite! Thank you.

Comment: It's their own file format, so no headers.  Each field is fixed length, so no delimiters.  The file formats changes slightly each time they update their software.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that doesn't sound too daunting. Is there anything I need to know about the encoding particularly? I can probably work things out myself if I can get enough help to make the first rung of the ladder!